# Optimal Delay for 'Update Later' Option in Software Update Dialog

Tags: updates, auto-update

Just curious what is the optimal delay for 'Update Later' option in software update dialog? 1 Week, 1 Month, till next program restart? So user doesn't get bothered too much, but in the same time not get stacked with outdated software?

Following picture illustrates what i mean
(I am not allowed to embed images yet to stackoverflow, so below is just plain link):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOwFz.png)

Maybe in some cases using 'Skip This Version' will be more 'user-friendly' instead of 'Update Later'?

Answer (score 0):

The remind me later usually depends on the type of application you are making.
You have really three  options. Remind Me Later reminds you after the next time you start the application. This is useful for applications that are started one a day or so.
Remind me in 5,15,30 minutes. Useful for applications where the user wants needs the newest features but wants to finish doing whatever they do in your app.
Auto update, tell them a new update is available and ask them when they want it to be install (5 Minutes, 15 Minutes, 1 Hour, Next Application Start).
Skip this version isn't recommended unless the applications create its own data and doesn't import data from previous versions of the application.
Remember you want to KISS it (Keep it Super Simple).